# Reference Arrays and Variables after proc tcl

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am in the process of creating a wireless sensor network using NS2. 20 Wireless Nodes are distributed randomly across an x-y plane, and using a distance calculation, the neighbors are found (the ones that a broadcast can reach). From the neighbors, I create clusters for each node starting with Node 0.

For example, starting with Node 0 as clusterhead, we would get an output like:

```
Cluster for Node 0 contains: 
1
3
8
```

From there, move to the next node NOT contained in there so:

```
Cluster for Node 2 contains: 
5
6
7
```

Using lists in TCL, I am having trouble referencing the cluster array changed in the `proc neighbors`. I am able to add elements to the list for Node 0 cluster. However, I can only do it inside the process and the loops create a 'reprinting' issue. I have tried different combinations of `global cluster` and `upvar`. How do I reference my cluster list AFTER the process?

Below is my current code with the output and reprint issue (the neighbors are correct, I am able to verify that in the simulator).

```
set cluster {}
set bool 0 

proc neighbors {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    global bool cluster 
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]
    set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]

    if {$d<40} {
        if {$nd1!=$nd2} {
            set bool 1

            if {$bool ==1} {
                puts "$nd1 AND $nd2"
                if {$nd1 == 0} {             
                    lappend cluster $nd2
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $::cluster]} {incr i} {
        puts "${i}=[lindex $::cluster $i]" 
    } 
}

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < $val(nn)} {incr j} {
        $ns at 0.0 "neighbors $node($i) $node($j) $i $j"
    }
}
```

Small section of Output (it repeats for every nd1 and nd2 combo) - For Node 0, the the 0-7 identifier is referencing the correct neighbor.

```
0 AND 19
0=2
1=4
2=5
3=6
4=10
5=13
6=15
7=19
0=2
1=4
2=5
3=6
4=10
5=13
6=15
7=19
0=2
1=4
2=5
3=6
4=10
5=13
6=15
7=19
```

Now, if I move the cluster index OUTSIDE the proc. I get no output referring to the cluster list.

```
set cluster {}
set bool 0 

proc neighbors {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
  global bool cluster 
  set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
  set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
  set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
  set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]
  set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]

  if {$d<40 && $nd1!=$nd2} {
            puts "$nd1 AND $nd2"
            if {$nd1 == 0} {             
                lappend cluster $nd2
            }
    }
}


for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < $val(nn)} {incr j} {
        puts "$i, $j"
        $ns at 0.0 "neighbors $node($i) $node($j) $i $j"
    }
}

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $::cluster]} {incr i} {
    puts "${i}=[lindex $::cluster $i]" 
}
```

Output (just for Node 0):

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
...
0 AND 4
0 AND 6
0 AND 8
0 AND 9
0 AND 11
0 AND 12
0 AND 15
0 AND 16
0 AND 19
```

Although I would expect/want something like

```
...
0 AND 15
Cluster for Node 0:
0=8
1=12
2=15
```

How do I reference this array/list properly? Also, I feel like I will need to use the `bool == 1` later as well. In simple tests, I cannot reference it's change outside the proc as well.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't worked with ns2, but I can't say I understand what you are trying to do, but the result for the one where you have tried moving the cluster index outside the proc makes sense because the loop occurs before the proc is called, and then when the proc is executed, there is no printing that can occur. I don't think the issue is with how you are referencing `cluster`, but more with the logic. For instance, the first `if` could be written as `if {$d<40 && $nd1!=$nd2} { ... }` and the bool check is redundant, since it will always be 1 at that point (having set it to 1 just one line earlier)

Comment: As to why it might appear as duplicate might be that for one iteration, `$d` was below 40, and for the following 2 iterations, `$d` was above 40 so only the printing of the clusters happened without the `$nd1 AND $nd2` part being printed. I suggest you use something like `puts "Results for $i, $j"` just before the line `$ns at 0.0...` inside the loop to give a better indication of what's happening.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you for the suggestions. I had the ```if {$d<40 && $nd1!=$nd2} { ... }``` at one point, but for some (logic) reason it did not work. I have gotten it to work in the edit (see the 2nd main code block). However, even moving my cluster call/print after the proc call, I still get no output.

Also, for the ```puts $i, $j```, I get exactly what I expect. It runs through ```i=0``` to ```j=19``` then goes to the next ```i```. No unexpected results or better indication of what is going on with duplicates.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but the calculation of `d` ought to be `set d [expr {int(hypot($x2-$x1, $y2-$y1))}]`; the `hypot` function (for “hypotenuse”) is designed to be used for exactly this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. The ***I THINK*** the problems lies in the fact that the simulator must run all process in the code - not the actual TCL compiler. Either way, adding a new `proc printCluster` gives you a single output of your cluster along with the neighbors.

```
set ::cluster {}
set bool 0 

proc neighbors {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
  global bool ::cluster {}
  set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
  set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
  set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
  set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]
  set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]

  if {$d<40 && $nd1!=$nd2} {
            puts "$nd1 AND $nd2"
            if {$nd1 == 0} {             
                lappend ::cluster $nd2
            }
    }
    proc printCluster {} {
        puts "Node 0 Cluster:"
        for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $::cluster]} {incr i} {
            puts "[lindex $::cluster $i]"
        }
}
}


for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < $val(nn)} {incr j} {
        $ns at 0.0 "neighbors $node($i) $node($j) $i $j"
    }
}

$ns at 0.0 "printCluster"
```

Output:

```
... 
Node 0 Cluster:
1
2
6
15
18
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. A simulation ex with your code https://www.dropbox.com/s/am2wakwljlmsz5r/Print-Cluster__Lcode.tar.gz?dl=0 .... Note : The tcl interpreter is wish : Can be deleted. Never used with ns2 →  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing  .... Note2 : 'ns' isn't really "speaking" tcl, but **otcl** .